# Page template or child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i created an html homepage  more likely a squeeze page, which i want to use as the homepage to my blog , i was thinking of making it a page template, so i enqueued all the script and style and it seems to be that, the former theme header.php is showing on the new one i created,  this seems to be a serious challenge.

Because enqueued script and styles goes to the header, if i alter the it distorts the blog main header, And besides that i dnt want the squeeze page header to be reused in any part of the theme.

So my queation is. is there any way i could enquee styles and script without it going to the header.php or infact, is there any other way to add styles and script without the enqueeing it in function.php.

Thanks in advance guys for your support i would really appreciate it.

Comment: u want your homepage header to be different from the rest of your blog pages?

Answer (score 0):

I want to know if to there os anoda way to add sttles nd script wiiout enqueeung dem in d function.php